# MYSql: which one is better for get ROWS? (Where IN ()) or foreach

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table `users` include **100000** rows

now, which one is better for SELECT?

**A.**

```
select * 
from users 
where user_id IN    
(5,12,5979,124,455594,5444,..........4568,10001,546,9979,21315);
```

**B.**

```
`$user_ids = {5,12,5979,124,455594,5444,.......4568,10001,546,9979,21315};`

foreach ($user_ids as $id) {
     select * from users where user_id = $id;
}
```

I would like to know the better solution from this

Comment: A good rule-of-thumb is NEVER execute a query inside a loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first option is better.Using the select query inside loop will be requesting the database server each time during the loop which can affect optimization of system

Comment: where user_id IN(count no limit? )

Comment: You can either store the entire id's in an array and use implode to make the array as string

Answer (score 1):

The better is the solution A where user_id in (...)

With the solution A you perform the query one time only

with the forarch loop you perform the select query each time 
and this with serious impact on performance  .

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use **A** Option because each time the loop will query the database and that is not proper. You just take all the data and use it as per your requirement.So Choosing  Option **A** will be a good idea.